# Run Sharepoint Audit Log Reports for User Group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, groups, auditing, log

Cannot find a way to run audit log reports for user groups. There is User picker in Custom Report wich allows selection of Groups also. But errors (with "User Not Found" message) when you run the report with Group selection.

Is there anyway to run Audit report on Sharepoint 2013 server for specific User Group?

Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to run audit log report for specific user group in the SharePoint 2013 server.